# rich:column under rich:extendedDataTable doesn't render id as id

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

i want a rich:column to render a id attribute in html. But it seems, that the given id will only be rendered as part of the class. I need the id for rendering only one column.

Here is my sample code:

```
            <rich:extendedDataTable id="table" value="${fn:split('A,B,C', ',')}" var="letter">
                <rich:column id="letter_id">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Letter" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{letter}" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

rendered result:

```
<tr id="landForm:table:0:n">
 <td>
  <div class="rf-edt-c rf-edt-c-letter_id">
   <div class="rf-edt-c-cnt">A</div>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

A rich:column under rich:dataTable renders the id. Regarding the Taglib description there should be no difference, if the column is under a dataTable or an extendedDataTable.

My workaround was to put a panelGroup below the column. This helped for rendering the column value. But i need to render the column, because i have to attach a different css style when editing the column.

Any ideas?

Comment: The id thing will be fixed in 4.5.3, at the same time you can't really rerender a whole column and if you just want to change some CSS then AJAX request is not necessary. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a editable row. The input fields will be rendered, when the item is in edit mode, which is archived by an edit button in each row.

Comment: Thx!
I have a editable row. The fields will be rendered regarding the edit mode. There is an edit button in each row. When scrolling down and start editing a cell which is normally not visible, a render @form or '<table>' scrolls the table up, which is frustrating for the user.

I couldn't select the column, because of the missing id. This problem i solved with the panelGroup. After that, a problem with the style sheets arise. The class of the <td> changed, when editing. I solved this with a Javascript in oncomplete="$('div.inlineEditTable td').has('.editing').addClass('editing');"